# Multiple message types with spring JMS

Tags: java, spring-jms

I have 2 message types `DealCreateDto` and `DealUpdateDto`.

How can I work with 2 different message data types in one spring application? Should I create 2 JmsTemplate instances for each message type or something else?

For JMS using embedded ActiveMQ and `MessageConverter` implementations:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DealCreateDtoConverter implements MessageConverter {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Message toMessage(@NonNull Object object, @NonNull Session session) {
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setText(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
        return message;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public DealCreateDto fromMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(((TextMessage) message).getText(), DealCreateDto.class);
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DealUpdateDtoConverter implements MessageConverter {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Message toMessage(@NonNull Object object, @NonNull Session session) {
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setText(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
        return message;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public DealUpdateDto fromMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(((TextMessage) message).getText(), DealUpdateDto.class);
    }
}
```

But as I understood one `JmsTemplate` can contain only one message converter, and when I try to use both:

```
private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Override
public void create(@NonNull DealCreateDto deal) {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(ActiveMqConfig.DEAL_CREATE_QUEUE, deal);
}

@JmsListener(destination = ActiveMqConfig.DEAL_CREATE_QUEUE, containerFactory = "jmsFactory")
public void receiveCreate(@Payload @NonNull DealCreateDto dealDto) {
}

@Override
public void update(@NonNull DealUpdateDto deal) {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(ActiveMqConfig.DEAL_UPDATE_QUEUE, deal);
}

@JmsListener(destination = ActiveMqConfig.DEAL_UPDATE_QUEUE, containerFactory = "jmsFactory")
public void receiveUpdate(@Payload @NonNull DealUpdateDto dealDto) {
}
```

Throwing an exception:

```
2022-08-16 08:41:19:131 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert object of type [ltd.mydomain.dto.deal.DealCreateDto] to JMS message. Supported message payloads are: String, byte array, Map<String,?>, Serializable object.] with root cause
org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert object of type [ltd.mydomain.dto.deal.DealCreateDto] to JMS message. Supported message payloads are: String, byte array, Map<String,?>, Serializable object.
    at org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.toMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$convertAndSend$5(JmsTemplate.java:661)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:604)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$send$3(JmsTemplate.java:586)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661)
    at ltd.mydomain.service.DealServiceImpl.create(DealServiceImpl.java:39)
    at ltd.mydomain.service.DealServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4deee829.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704)
    at ltd.mydomain.service.DealServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b58a53c.create(<generated>)
    at ltd.mydomain.controller.DealController.create(DealController.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Jms configuration:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class ActiveMqConfig {

    public static final String DEAL_CREATE_QUEUE = "deal-create-queue";

    public static final String DEAL_UPDATE_QUEUE = "deal-update-queue";

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsFactory(
            @NonNull ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            @NonNull DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this violates the Liskov Substitution Principle, but is compact and works.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageConverterImpl implements MessageConverter {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    // set all message types here or get as bean from config class
    private final List<Class<?>> messageTypes = List.of(
            DealCreateDto.class,
            DealUpdateDto.class
    );

    private final Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, Boolean>> toMessageFunMap = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<String, Function<Message, Object>> fromMessageFunMap = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        messageTypes.forEach(clazz -> {
            toMessageFunMap.put(clazz, o -> o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(clazz));
            fromMessageFunMap.put(clazz.getName(), message -> getMsg(message, clazz));
        });
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private Object getMsg(@NonNull Message message, @NonNull Class<?> clazz) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(((TextMessage) message).getText(), clazz);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Message toMessage(@NonNull Object object, @NonNull Session session) {
        Class<?> clazz = toMessageFunMap.keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(cz -> toMessageFunMap.get(cz).apply(object))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow();
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setText(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
        message.setStringProperty("className", clazz.getName());
        return message;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public Object fromMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
        String type = message.getStringProperty("className");
        return fromMessageFunMap.get(type).apply(message);
    }
}
```